# Does it makes sense to use address(this).call()?

Tags: solidity, contract-design

I have such following smart contract:

```
function a() external onlyOwner {
  _a();
}

function b() external onlyOwner {
  _b();
}

function _a() internal {
  // do smh
}

function _b() internal {
  // do smh
}
```

`a` and `b` should be only called by the owner of the contract. But I also need a logic for myself to execute these functions for me to pay the gas. So I have another such function:

```
function verifySigner(bytes memory signature) internal {
  // recover signer from the signature
  // do smh
}
```

There are 2 ways I see to make this work.

1_ Make 2 different external functions, one verifying the signature and redirecting to function `a`, and same for function `b`

2_ Make a single function that takes the function signature in the parameters and calls it with the low level call after verifying the signer as follows:

```
function delegate(bytes memory signature, bytes memory fnSignature) external onlyByMe {
  // verifySigner(signature)

  address(this).call(
    fnSignature
  );
}
```

Which one should I go with and why?

Comment: You can use [`encodeCall`](https://twitter.com/solidity_lang/status/1472974606239731720?lang=en) to get type safety. See Hari's [topics in Solidity](https://hrkrshnn.com/t/ethglobal2022.pdf?utm_source=pocket_mylist).

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me according to my research and experiments with gas efficiency, first option is more suitable.

With the second option deployment is cheaper, but due to `call`'s overhead, function calls are a bit more expensive. And since my contract requires a good amount of interaction, and deployment is going to occur only once, the first option is the better choice for me.